# How to edit WordPress theme code live?

Tags: html, wordpress, atom-editor

So I use Atom for web development and I have just created a duplicate WordPress theme that I want to edit on the fly so that when I save changes, it automatically updates on the server. I can do this on Shopify using the Theme Editor but is there a way of doing this on WordPress?

I basically just don't want to have to download and upload to FTP every time I make an edit.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like this can be helpful: https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp

Answer (score 0):

To edit theme live you can use following steps.
1. Go to Appearance > Themes > Editor
2. Choose your theme from `Select theme to edit:` and click on `Select` Button.
3. Find file name under `Templates` (in which you want to update code)
4. If you don't found that file (in which you want to update code) you can change url as `/theme-editor.php?file=dir%2Ffile-name.php&theme=***`

```
Here `dir%2Ffile-name.php`
it is as `dir/file-name.php`
```

Like this you can add your file url & update that.

**Note:** You have to aware about theme's file structure.